# Zero's of a Character (Burnside's theorem)

Tags: group-theory, characters

A well-known theorem of Burnside states that any non-linear $\mathbb{C}$-irreducible character of a finite group vanishes on some conjugacy class of the group. My question is then comes naturally:

> Are there finite groups for which any non-linear $\mathbb{C}$-irreducible character vanishes on *exactly one* conjugacy class of the group? Have such groups studied, if exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such groups have been studied by $E.M. Zhmud$ in his paper **"On finite groups having an irreducible complex character with one class of zeros(1979)"**. However, you can very well also refer to [this link](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~jdixon/OneZero.pdf).